# Why can't I see a QXL device in my windows 10 kvm guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've been following the instructions here:
http://www.spice-space.org/page/WinQXL
To try and install the QXL driver on a windows 10 guest on an ubuntu machine with KVM.
The instructions mention that there should be a QXL device in the device manager. I cannot see such a device, only "basic display driver".

How do I make it appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a windows 8.1 driver that works.

I downloaded the RPM file linked below and used the `qxldod` driver for windows 8.1 following the same instructions on the site mentioned in the question. The screen resolution can now be changed although auto-scaling doesn't work.

The device will not show up as a QXL device until the driver is installed, update the driver on the 'microsoft basic display driver' item in device manager.

https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/latest/virtio-win-0.1.110-2.noarch.rpm